# Maybe a bug in DataFrame.reindex ?

Tags: python, pandas

python 2.7.11

pandas 0.18.1

when i try to do like this:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Ia','Ib'],['i1','i2','i3']])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['c','b','b','a','b','a'],'B':[10,-20,50,40,None,50],'C':[100,50,-30,-50,70,40]},index=idx)
print df.reindex(index=['Ib','Ia'],columns=['B','A','D'],level=0)
```

and then :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print df.reindex(index=['Ib','Ia'],columns=['B','A','D'],level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2741, in reindex
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2229, in reindex
    fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2682, in _reindex_axes
    limit, tolerance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2704, in _reindex_columns
    tolerance=tolerance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2330, in reindex
    return_indexers=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2636, in _join_level
    old_level = left.levels[level]
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'levels'
```

is that OK ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question: No, that is not OK!  And it's not a bug... really.

Consider the dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(4, 2),
                  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], ['C', 'D']]),
                  ['One', 'Two'])
df
```

[image]

I can reindex like this:

```
df.reindex(index=['a'], level=0)
#                       ^
#                       |
# Note the use of level here
```

[image]

When I do this:

```
df.reindex(columns=['Two'], level=0)
```

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'levels'
> ```

Quite simply telling me that I can't use `level` on an index that doesn't have levels.

Ok, fine.  But what if I do:

```
df.reindex(index=['a'], columns=['Two'], level=0)
```

Same error.  Apparently, `reindex` is assuming my `level` argument is going to the columns and not index when I pass both.

Let's test that idea:

```
df.T.reindex(columns=['a'], index=['Two'], level=0)
```

Uh, Oh!  Same error.  That theory is out.  Maybe, I have to have levels on both axes in order to use the `level` parameter when passing both index and columns.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Three'], ['One', 'Two']])
df
```

[image]

```
df.reindex(index=['a'], columns=['Three'], level=0)
```

[image]

**Success!**

It seems that if you pass `level`, all indices that you pass must have levels.  And, the `level` parameter will apply to all indices that are passed.

What does this mean for you?

Just do this:

```
df.reindex(index=['Ib','Ia'], level=0).reindex(columns=['B','A','D'])
```

Comment: That's right ! level && MultiIndex ! thank you for your answer !

Comment: @zhangtong if this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the answer